# Is One Piece Film Gold canon or not?

Tags: one-piece

In the film:

> Tezoro stated that Loffy defeated Doflamingo, and Sabo has the Flair-Flair Fruit's power. That puts the Gold film after their fight with Doflamingo.

Also

> After they defeated Doflamingo in the anime, they got separated from each other and Sanji went to his wedding and all that.

So is the film canon? If it is, when does it take place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you said, based on the time frame alone the movie cannot be placed anywhere in the manga story line since after Doflamingo was defeated the crew separated once more (the only possibility where this could happen is "far" into the future, after the upcoming reverie/Wano arc).

Also it's worth noting that Oda was only the executive producer on the film (he supervised the art direction), he did not write the story for it.

Generally everything outside the manga is considered non-canon unless Oda specifically declares something as belonging to the main story.

Comment: Thank you, is it possible that Oda will open up a time skip for the film or fit it in the timeline in the future? Or should we just leave it at that?@Proxy

Comment: i think he will leave it as it is. Even if he would include it in the timeskip it would be hard to place it, as the current arc is standing the SH are going to cause even more "problems" then they did with doflamingo and we would have a reference of that in the movie.  The movies are mostly similar to dragonball movies if you watched them, basically a "different timeline" side story

Comment: This wasn't the case with the Z film, that's why I asked

Comment: yeah thought you were referring to that, as far as i have understood it the character backstory is really canon but the movie story itself is not

Comment: No I meant how the films story fitted to the main timeline @Proxy

Comment: the story itself does not fit anywhere, the same case as with the new gold movie

Comment: It's turning in to a discussion here :), if you see the z film right after they introduce the character and then continue watching the anime you see that it fits without any confusion (like in gold). I was expecting the same thing from gold but that didn't happen

Comment: discussion is nice when its level headed :). Yeah, they have some reference from manga materials (unlike gold) but still i'm not sure where i would fit them. But to be honest i even don't remember everything that happened in the movies 100%, so maybe i'm wrong there and they can really be placed in manga story line. Maybe we will get some information in the future from the manga, but until then i personally don't view them as canon story

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I'm not saying that was cannon, I just say that it was nicely timed and didn't drift from the main time line. if you watch it, it will feel like a part of anime. unlike gold that was confusing

Comment: Yeah, it was more in the line with the rest of the story, that is true. Also characters like Shiki were mentioned in the manga before so they had more credibility then Tezoro.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is not.
Quoting from [here](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Non-Canon):

> Oda had occasionally been involved in non-canon material:
>
> Oda wrote the story for One Piece Film: Strong World and executive produced One Piece Film: Z and One Piece Film: Gold.

Comment: It is worth noting that Strong World (as I understand it) is therefore the only canon OP movie to date.